# Checking if value exists but not grouping it

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I am creating a view out of a table like this:

```
name        lastname        state       number_1        number_2
john        dal             TX          100             200
dave        pop                         100             300
tom         kim             LA          300             600
kyle        rom                         50              10  
kyle        rom             LA          50              10
```

I am trying to multiply `number_1` and `number_2` and have a column stating if `state` was present but not group by it:

```
SELECT name, lastname, number_1*number_2 as product,
CASE 
WHEN state IS NOT NULL 
THEN True 
ELSE False 
END AS state_present
GROUP BY name, lastname
```

When I run this I get that state needs to be used in aggregate function, my desired outcome would look like this:

```
name        lastname       product         state_present       
john        dal            200000          True
dave        pop            300000          False
tom         kim            1800000         True          
kyle        rom            500             False  
kyle        rom            500             True
```

Comment: Why use `group by` at all? You are not aggregating anything. Also: your case expression can be simplified to `state is not null as state_present`

Comment: This is a dummy data, in reality there are same values in columns `name` and `lastname`

Comment: You still don't need a group by. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ec1e2e6b6e7c7968d6e71445b361467a

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original version of the question.

Are you looking for a simple select with some expressions?

```
select name, lastname, (number_1 * number_2) as product,
       (state is not null) as state_present
from t;
```

Your question seems a bit misleading, because it mentions aggregation but I don't see how that would apply at all.

Comment: I've updated the table data, in the last two lines the same person with has one entry with a state and one without, the end result would be two lines where the name, last name is the same, product is still number_1*_number_2 but the state_present is False and True respectively. When I run this I am still getting `Invalid operation: column "table.state" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function;`

Comment: @JonasPalačionis: get rid of the `group by` it's not needed